# Another way to define resonance?

Tags: energy, definition, resonance

Considering descriptive (and not necessarily applied) physics, would it be proper to define resonance as:

**"One of the fundamental means of storing energy"**  ?

Of course there are other ways to store energy like pressurizing a gas, charging a capacitor or creating chemical bonds for examples.

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_storage) article on **energy storage** doesn't mention resonance anywhere as a means of storing energy, but only briefly when discussing applications it mentions resonance to

> .. tune radios to particular frequencies.

In all the examples of resonance I'm able to imagine, resonance 'traps' energy in an object or system, so in a sense the structure of the object or system that enables resonance allows the storage of energy. As one simple example, a mass-spring system stores some initial energy introduced by compressing or extending the spring, and that energy, assuming no dissipative losses flows between potential and kinetic states indefinitely.

Of course there are usually dissipative losses in real resonant systems, but I can think of at least a few examples where the losses are small compared to the systems ability to trap the energy.

I don't believe there are any examples of resonance where energy is *not* being stored [within the bounds of the system].

Comment: I've never heard resonance described as energy storage and can't see how it would be a particularly useful form of it.  It's often not a potential energy; but a cyclic kinetic to potential energy, so there are constant losses during kinetic portions.

Comment: "assuming no dissipative losses" That's a huge and prohibitive assumption when applied to the real world.  If we apply your definition to physical materials, it would imply a cyclical deformation of the materials, which would make it a highly inefficient way to "store" energy, since the energy would be quickly lost to heat.

Comment: Ignoring the hypothetical case of zero damping, the proposed definition isn't even true in many situations. Paradoxically, the rate of energy *loss* from a system when it is resonating is often a *maximum* not a minimum, because the energy dissipation increases as the amplitude increases.  (Of course the rate of energy *gain* by the system is also a maximum, because of the phase relationship between the motion of the system and the force supplying the energy.)

Comment: @JMac and others: Note I never mentioned the word *practical* in my question.  There is the topic of *descriptive* physics, apart from applied physics and on the subject of energy we know that it is conserved, that it can flow through space and matter, and that it can be trapped (or stored) either in transient states or indefinitely (in chemical bonds for example). So regarding *descriptive* physics why can't we say resonance 'stores' energy?

Comment: @alephzero conceptually you don't need a driving force for resonance; a sufficient initial condition will do.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what a definition needs to do for the people who use it.

One thing it *must* do is allow you to identify instances of the thing defined.

Having read your proposed definition I have no way whatsoever of guessing from it if a system might exhibit resonance nor of spotting a resonance when it does occur, so at best you are offering up a description of one, non-definitive property.

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully make my intent clearer. Of course resonant systems have other properties, but in terms of energy they do 'trap' the energy even if momentarily, right?

Comment: A vibrating system "traps" energy exactly the same way whether it is resonating or not. The amount of energy "trapped" only depends on the *amplitude* of the motion, not on the fact that it is "resonating".